# How do I check 2 columns in 2 separate data frames for value unique to one column but not the other?

Tags: r

So I have 2 separate data frames, which both have a column called "team". The list of teams in df1$team should have the exact same number of teams (130) as the list of teams in df2$team, but df2$team has 20 fewer teams in it. How can I figure out what those 20 teams are using R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a minimal reproducable example for your question:

```
# set up dummy data: 2 dfs with one team column each
df1 <- data.frame(team = c("a", "b", "c"))

df2 <- data.frame(team = c("b", "c"))
```

you can use the negation of the in-operator to obtain just the team names by using base R:

```
df1$team[!df1$team %in% df2$team]
[1] "a"
```

One possible option is a anti join from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2, by = "team")
   team
1    a
```

Anyhow I advise you to check for the opposite case (teams from df2 not in df1) as theoretically is seems possible by your description.